# How to get the coordinate of a THREE.JS object on the map

Tags: three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl

After loaded an object to a map using this example (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/), how can you retrieve the object's coordinate back? I want to set the centre when the object moves.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: If you are going to play seriously with mapbox and three.js, I’d recommend you to check [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) out. I’m maintaining this repo, and it will allow you to move the object, animate it and always have full control of its position and pivotal center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you cannot do it, unless you assign `modelAsMercatorCoordinate` as a variable in the new object `userData` when it’s instantiated and before it’s added into the scene.
To find it in any other part of the code, you’ll need to loop over `this.scene.children` and find the object in that collection, considering there are also 2 lights added, it will be `this.scene.children[2]` but it’s much better to assign to it a name and then look for it through that with `this.scene.getObjectByName`

Comment: Hey @jscastro, thx for your answer, is that right this stored `modelAsMercatorCoordinate` won't auto update its coords after the object moves? I'm having a play with your threebox truck example, it's got exactly what I'm looking for, the object has a real `position` attribute when it moves, did you had to manually call `truck.set` in the `animate` function? I'm still learning my way  through this and having some issue when loading multiple GLB animation(idle, walk) for my character, the `11-animation` example in Threebox is using one GLB instead

Comment: Actually the animation is partially working, it will start to animate when I moves the map around to trigger the re-rendering.

Comment: Good to hear you're advancing... in the truck example from threebox the animation is made by `truck.followPath` method not by a `truck.set`. Let me know in the repo if you have any question or issue that I can help with